# Не находит нужный логин при авторизации

Tags: php, авторизация

Помогите разобраться с авторизацией, не находит нужный логин при авторизации, хотя такой есть в базе. http://ideone.com/KYya2A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим строчку 80:

```
 $query = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login_auth");
```

Разве переменную `$login_auth` не нужно брать в кавычки? В ней же строковое значение содержится.

Comment: благодарю за ответ, я совсем забыл про кавычки потому что постоянно выбирал данные по id а там не надо кавычки так как числовое значение - наверное так. Можете на пальцах объяснить что значит строковое значение и чем отличается $data от '$data' ?

Comment: @sew810i9 ну вы же различаете строковое и числовое значение!) Просто в sqlite числовые можно не брать в кавычки, а строковые - обязательно (по моему даже не строковые значения, а все, отличные от числовых).